# 4 divs in Swiper Slide

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, swiper.js

I have a swiper slider.

I need put 4 divs in one slide, and 2 divs in the second.

In the first slide I have 2 divs and 4 divs in the second.

```
function loadcontent() {
  var id = $('.catslide>.swiper-wrapper>.swiper-slide-active').attr('data-id');
  $.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "../showthis.php",
    data: {
      id: id,
      rand: 1
    },
    datatype: 'json',
    success: function(data) {
      var height = $('#slideadv').height();
      $('#slideadv').height(height);
      mySwiper.removeAllSlides();
      mySwiper.appendSlide(data);
      mySwiper.update();
    }
  });
}
```

//showthis.php //

```
$query3 =
  "SELECT * FROM adv_items  WHERE category_id='$id' AND adv_type='Standard' AND hide='show' ORDER BY RAND()";
$advst = $db - > prepare($query3);
$advst - > fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
$advst - > execute();
$text = '';


foreach(array_chunk($advst - > fetchAll(), 4, true) as $advsts) {
  {
    echo '<div class="swiper-slide">';
    foreach($advsts as $kicks) {
      echo '<div class="col-md-6 advertising">';
      echo '<div class="company-logo"><img src="./'.$kicks['clogo'].
      '" alt="..."></div>';
      echo '<div class="company-contcs"><p class="company-title">'.$kicks[
        'cname'].
      '</p><a href="tel:'.$kicks['phone1'].
      '">Телефон: '.$kicks['phone1'].
      '</a><a href="'.$kicks['curl'].
      '">'.$kicks['curl'].
      '</a></div>';
      echo '<p class="company-desc">'.substr($kicks['text'], 0, 600).
      '</p>';
      echo "</div>";
    }
    echo '</div>';
  }
}
```

// mypage.php //

```
$query3 =
  "SELECT * FROM adv_items  WHERE category_id='$id' AND adv_type='Standard' AND hide='show' ORDER BY RAND()";
$advst = $db - > prepare($query3);
$advst - > fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
$advst - > execute();
$text = '';

foreach(array_chunk($advst - > fetchAll(), 4, true) as $advsts) {
  {
    echo '<div class="swiper-slide">';
    foreach($advsts as $kicks) {
      echo '<div class="col-md-6 advertising">';
      echo '<div class="company-logo"><img src="./'.$kicks['clogo'].
      '" alt="..."></div>';
      echo '<div class="company-contcs"><p class="company-title">'.$kicks[
        'cname'].
      '</p><a href="tel:'.$kicks['phone1'].
      '">Телефон: '.$kicks['phone1'].
      '</a><a href="'.$kicks['curl'].
      '">'.$kicks['curl'].
      '</a></div>';
      echo '<p class="company-desc">'.substr($kicks['text'], 0, 600).
      '</p>';
      echo "</div>";
    }
    echo '</div>';
  }
}
```

// mypage.php //

```
<div id = "webslider" class = "row webslider">
  <div class = "container">
    <div class = "swiper-container categories-advertising">
    <!-- Additional required wrapper -->
    <div id = "slideadv" class = "swiper-wrapper slideadv">
      <?php 
        foreach (array_chunk($advst->fetchAll(), 4, true) as $advsts) {
          {
            echo '<div class="swiper-slide">';
            foreach ($advsts as $kicks) {
      ?> 
      <div class = "col-md-6 advertising">
        <div class = "company-logo">
          <img src = "./<?php echo $kicks['clogo'] ?>" alt = "...">
  </div> 
  <div class = "company-contcs">
    <p class = "company-title"> 
      <?php 
        echo $kicks['cname'] 
      ?> 
    </p> 
    <a href = "tel:<?php echo $kicks['phone1'] ?>"> Телефон:
      <?php 
        echo $kicks['phone1'] 
      ?> 
    </a>
    <a href = "<?php echo $kicks['curl'] ?>"> 
      <?php 
        echo $kicks['curl'] 
      ?> 
    </a> 
  </div> 
  <p class = "company-desc">
    <?php 
      echo substr($kicks['text'], 0, 600) 
    ?> 
  </p> 
</div>
<?php
  }
    echo '</div>';
  }
?>
<?php 
  } 
?> 
</div> 
<div class = "swiper-button-next"> 
  <img width = "30px" src = "./img/scroll-arrow-right.svg" alt = "arrow right">
</div> 
<div class = "swiper-button-prev"> 
  <img width = "30px" src = "./img/scroll-arrow-left.svg" alt = "arrow left">
</div> 
</div> 
</div> 
</div>
```

I use javascript to update this slider.

Comment: Hi, please provide your HTML code as well

Answer (score 0):

I find the solution without `array_chunk`. I use `slidesPerColumn` and `slidesPerGroup` in my slider. Here is the code:

```
//define swiper// 

var mySwiper = new Swiper('.swiper-container', {
        direction: 'horizontal',
        slidesPerView: '2',
        slidesPerColumn: '2',
        spaceBetween: 0,
        slidesPerGroup: '1',
        slidesPerColumnFill: 'column',
        touchRatio: '2',
        nextButton: '.swiper-button-next',
        prevButton: '.swiper-button-prev'
    });
```

**mypage.php**

```
<div class="swiper-container categories-advertising">
                <!-- Additional required wrapper -->
                <div id="slideadv" class="swiper-wrapper slideadv">
                        <?php foreach ($advst->fetchAll() as $kicks) { ?>
                            <div class="swiper-slide">
                                    <div class="col-md-12 advertising">
                                        <div class="company-logo">
                                            <img src="./<?php echo $kicks['clogo'] ?>" alt="...">
                                        </div>
                                        <div class="company-contcs">
                                            <p class="company-title"><?php echo $kicks['cname'] ?></p>
                                            <a href="tel:<?php echo $kicks['phone1'] ?>">Телефон: <?php echo $kicks['phone1'] ?></a>
                                            <a href="<?php echo $kicks['curl'] ?>"><?php echo $kicks['curl'] ?></a>
                                        </div>
                                        <p class="company-desc">
                                            <?php echo substr($kicks['text'], 0, 600) ?>
                                        </p>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            <?php }?>
                </div>
                <div class="swiper-button-next"><img width="30px" src="./img/scroll-arrow-right.svg" alt="arrow right">
                </div>
                <div class="swiper-button-prev"><img width="30px" src="./img/scroll-arrow-left.svg" alt="arrow left">
                </div>
            </div>
```

**showthis.php** this is for ajax response

```
$query3 = "SELECT * FROM adv_items  WHERE category_id='$id' AND adv_type='STANDARD' AND hide='show' ORDER BY RAND()";
$advst = $db->prepare($query3);
$advst->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
$advst->execute();

foreach ($advst->fetchAll() as $kicks)
        {
            echo '<div class="swiper-slide">';
            echo '<div class="col-md-12 advertising">';
            echo '<div class="company-logo"><img src="./' . $kicks['clogo'] . '" alt="..."></div>';
            echo '<div class="company-contcs"><p class="company-title">' . $kicks['cname'] . '</p><a href="tel:' . $kicks['phone1'] . '">Phone: ' . $kicks['phone1'] . '</a><a href="' . $kicks['curl'] . '">' . $kicks['curl'] . '</a></div>';
            echo '<p class="company-desc">' . substr($kicks['text'], 0, 600) . '</p>';
            echo "</div>";
            echo '</div>';
        }
```